# Angular custom directive not working

Tags: angularjs

I have 2 things to do:

1. custom directive for dropdowns
2. custom directive for upload

> `var app=angular.module('app.directives', []);`
>
> ```
> app.directive('dropdowns', function() {alert("dropdown directive");
>   return {
>       restrict: 'AE',
>       templateUrl: 'html/uploadFile.html'
>   };
> });
>
> app.directive('uploadDir', function() {
>   alert("upload directive");
>   return {
>       restrict : 'AE',
>       templateUrl : 'html/dropdowns.html'
>   };
> });
> ```

The directive for dropdown is working
But the directive for upload is not working(the alert message in uploadDir directive is not getting displayed)

Is the syntax correct?

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <title>upload using directive</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.13.0.js"></script>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css"/>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/controllers/controllers.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/services/services.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/directives/directives.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<div dropdowns></div>
<div uploadDir></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `<div upload-dir></div>`. Directive names in camel case are normalised with dashes when matching against HTML elements.